# Can't run `npm start` from VS Code terminal, but it works from `cmd`

Tags: javascript, reactjs, node.js, package.json, npm-start

My package.json:

```
{
  "name": "my-app",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start",
    "lint": "next lint"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^18",
    "react-dom": "^18",
    "next": "14.1.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "typescript": "^5",
    "@types/node": "^20",
    "@types/react": "^18",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18",
    "autoprefixer": "^10.0.1",
    "postcss": "^8",
    "tailwindcss": "^3.3.0",
    "eslint": "^8",
    "eslint-config-next": "14.1.0"
  }
}
```

It works when using `cmd` but I still get an error.

[![This is after I click the link to `localhost` in `cmd`][1]][1]

I want to see what my web page looks like from Live Server. I don't know how to see it when using Node/React.

*edit
the output from npm start in command show error like this

```
npm ERR! Missing script: "start"
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Did you mean one of these?
npm ERR!     npm star # Mark your favorite packages
npm ERR!     npm stars # View packages marked as favorites
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! To see a list of scripts, run:
npm ERR!   npm run

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2024-02-29T00_01_11_608Z-debug-0.log
```

after that i type npm run, but nothing happened. is there any error on script in package.json?
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/WeLxvl.png

Comment: Hi, welcome to stackoverflow. When running the command, do you have any error ? What's the output. Your question seams to be missing some critical information. Please refer to the [ask] section and refine it.

Comment: Are you sure you are in the correct path when using VsCode?

Answer (score -1):

1. This could be a number of issues, I would suggest if you haven't already install and use [NVM (Node version manager)](https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm) to help manage your node version to make sure your node installation isn't the problem
2. **"npm start"** is the wrong syntax since you are trying to run the scripts defined in your package.json; the correct syntax is **"npm run start"**

This issue could be elsewhere but without an error log its difficult to diagnose the correct issue

Comment: `npm start` is [entirely correct](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v6/commands/npm-start).